# SignalR Client returns HTTP error 400 Bad request

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using a SignalR Client connection using `HubConnection`. When calling `Start()`, an `System.Net.WebException` is thrown with the following message:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

The server response is:

> Not a valid web socket request.

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was with the configuration of IIS.

You have to install the `WebSocket Protocol` support in order to connect to SignalR using WebSockets.

[image]